# append_path: command not found error for installation hadoop on manjaro

Tags: linux, hadoop, manjaro, flatpak

when ı run this code `hadoop version`, ı get this error

```
/etc/profile.d/flatpak-bindir.sh: line 8: append_path: command not found
bash: append_path: command not found
bash: append_path: command not found
bash: append_path: command not found
/usr/lib/hadoop-3.3.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2386: 
HADOOP_VERSİON_USER: invalid variable name
/usr/lib/hadoop-3.3.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2489: 
HADOOP_VERSİON_OPTS: invalid variable name
Hadoop 3.3.1
Source code repository https://github.com/apache/hadoop.git -r a3b9c37a397ad4188041dd80621bdeefc46885f2
Compiled by ubuntu on 2021-06-15T05:13Z
Compiled with protoc 3.7.1
From source with checksum 88a4ddb2299aca054416d6b7f81ca55
This command was run using /usr/lib/hadoop-3.3.1/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.3.1.jar
```

/etc/profile.d/flatpak-bindir.sh file;

```
if [ -n "$XDG_DATA_HOME" ] && [ -d "$XDG_DATA_HOME/flatpak/exports/bin" ]; then
  append_path "$XDG_DATA_HOME/flatpak/exports/bin"
elif [ -n "$HOME" ] && [ -d "$HOME/.local/share/flatpak/exports/bin" ]; then
  append_path "$HOME/.local/share/flatpak/exports/bin"
fi

if [ -d /var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin ]; then
  append_path /var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin
fi
```

what should ı do for solve 'command not found' error

Comment: The error is with flatpak, nothing to do with hadoop

Comment: so what should ı do? ı need install hadoop on manjaro

Comment: I understand that. You could start by removing this profile file. Or you could actually define `append_path` function somehow to do whatever it needs to do. Seems like a bug in Arch https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=259400

Comment: Besides that, you're not getting actual fatal errors. The output shows `Hadoop 3.3.1`,as you'd expect. If you want to actually run hadoop cluster, the version command won't do that

Comment: I added append_path function to the scripts following the below link. (It seems to work fine now.) https://gist.github.com/Axxon/c150339eba06dd5cd8ec8b9e2904e40e

Comment: Thank you @rohith ı solved append path error

Comment: ı can not even run "version" command? how can ı run hadoop cluster? when ı write start-all.sh command bash can not found the command ı installed singlenode and multinode hadoop on ubuntu but ı dont installed hadoop on manjaro

Comment: ı follow this source for hadoop https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Hadoop ı need configurations but first ı should fix what ı see first mistakes. There is a just /usr/lib/hadoop-3.3.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-functions.sh error, should ı open new question or can ı continue from here?